# In chisel6.2.0, how to use hex file to init memory and test it?

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

I have the same problem as [this one: in-chisel-3-how-to-initialize-memory-test-code-with-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649473/in-chisel-3-how-to-initialize-memory-test-code-with-text-file), my test code indicates that loadMemoryFromFile makes no sense. I think my filepath is correct, but it just not work.
I use chisel6.2.0. Here is the structure of my project :

```bash
example
└── src
│   └── hex
│   │   └── example.hex.txt
│   └── main/scala/circuit
│   │             └── IMemory.scala
│   └── test/scala/circuit
│                 └── IMemorySpec.scala
└--build.sbt
```

**build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.12"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0"
ThisBuild / organization := "%ORGANIZATION%"

val chiselVersion = "6.2.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "%NAME%",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.chipsalliance" %% "chisel" % chiselVersion,
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % "test"
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-Xcheckinit",
      "-Ymacro-annotations"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "org.chipsalliance" % "chisel-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full
    )
  )
```

**example.hex.txt**

```
003100b3
40628033
06432283
06512423
064000ef
```

**IMemory.scala**

```scala
package circuit

import chisel3._
import chisel3.util.experimental.loadMemoryFromFileInline
import circt.stage.ChiselStage

class IMemoryIO extends Bundle {
  val rdAddr = Input(UInt(5.W))
  val rdData = Output(UInt(32.W))
  val wrAddr = Input(UInt(5.W))
  val wrData = Input(UInt(32.W))
  val wrEna = Input(UInt(1.W))
}

class IMemory(memoryFile: String = "") extends Module {
  val io = IO(new IMemoryIO)
  val mem = SyncReadMem(1024, UInt(32.W))
  io.rdData := mem.read(io.rdAddr)
  io.rdData := mem(io.rdAddr)
  when(io.wrEna === 1.U) {
    mem.write(io.wrAddr, io.wrData)
  }
  if (memoryFile.trim().nonEmpty) {
    loadMemoryFromFileInline(mem, memoryFile)
  }
}
```

**IMemorySpec.scala**

```scala
package circuit
import chisel3._
import chisel3.experimental.BundleLiterals._
import chisel3.simulator.EphemeralSimulator._
import org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.must.Matchers
import java.io.File
class IMemorySpec extends AnyFreeSpec with Matchers {
  "write memory" in {
    simulate(new IMemory("src/hex/example.hex.txt")) { dut =>
      dut.io.wrAddr.poke(4.U)
      dut.io.wrEna.poke(1.U)
      dut.io.wrData.poke(0x003100b3.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(4.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x003100b3.U)
    }
  }
  "loadMemory from file" in {
    simulate(new IMemory("src/hex/example.hex.txt")) { dut =>
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(0.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x003100b3.U)
    }
  }
}
```

when I run `sbt "testOnly circuit.IMemorySpec`, the output is :

```bash
[info] - file should exist
[info] - write memory
[info] - loadMemory from file *** FAILED ***
[info]   chisel3.simulator.PeekPokeAPI$FailedExpectationException: Failed Expectation: Observed value '0' != 3211443. Expectation failed: observed value 0 != 3211443
```

`Observed value '0' != 3211443.`. I can't read the data I expect.

I can sure it is not a path mistake. because when I'm using chisel5.1.0 and chiseltest， it works。
Here is my build.sbt.

```
// See README.md for license details.

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.12"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0"
ThisBuild / organization := "%ORGANIZATION%"

val chiselVersion = "5.1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "%NAME%",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.chipsalliance" %% "chisel" % chiselVersion,
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "5.0.2" % "test"
    ),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      "-deprecation",
      "-feature",
      "-Xcheckinit",
      "-Ymacro-annotations"
    ),
    addCompilerPlugin(
      "org.chipsalliance" % "chisel-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full
    )
  )
```

and my test

```scala
package circuit

import chisel3._
import chiseltest._

import org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec
import chisel3.experimental.BundleLiterals._

class IMemorySpec extends AnyFreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {
  "memory initial should work by example.hex.txt" in {
    test(new IMemory("src/hex/example.hex.txt")) { dut =>
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(0.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x003100b3.U)
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(1.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x40628033.U)
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(2.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x06432283.U)
      dut.io.rdAddr.poke(3.U)
      dut.clock.step()
      dut.io.rdData.expect(0x06512423.U)
    }
  }
}
```

it works as I expect.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. I have the same problem, maybe it could be a good idea to open an issue on repository https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel/issues ?